# What consumes memory in linux

Tags: linux, shell, server-administration

I use atop cmd to check memory usage.
on the screenshot use can I see I have 1gb total, and 300mb free.
how do I found out what consumes other ~700mb?
I tried to use atop cmd, but that doesn't give me much information.

[image]

Comment: Why don't to try htop command? ? It provides a better interface to sort based on many factor like memory, cpu, time, etc .

Comment: I think this is better suited to ServerFault than the programmer specific StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

a memory leak occurs when a process doesn't give memory back that it doesn't need anymore
so first run `top` and type `>` key to sort by memory utilization or virtual memory utilization
you should review how much swap you are using in `/proc/meminfo` then check the `inactive(anon)` if it has high value that is bigger than the swap memory then make your swap is greater than it
finally, run `free -m` to see the memory details
if you find cache is high run the following command

> `echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches; sync`

then run `free -m` again to see the changes

Answer (score 1):

I think glances utility is better suited for this purpose. It is more user friendly and provides various options for real time server stats. For more information about the utility, see [this](https://www.tecmint.com/glances-an-advanced-real-time-system-monitoring-tool-for-linux/) page.